# Monospaced html formatting jlabel

Tags: html, jlabel

I am creating an output window for a program dealing with matrices. It is supposed to print out the preformed command along with a formatted version of the matrix. But I am having problems with the alignment. I know the `String.format` works because i have a `toString()` method that works correctly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqfzG.png]

Notice how the second and third rows are not correctly spaced. This is because the 100.00 has completely filled the formatted string where as the 0.00's need extra spaces to fill the string(see toHtml()). I believe this has something to do with the way that the HTML is being displayed but im not sure. My guess is that the spaces behind the zeros are not being displayed properly or are being combined.

Here are the methods involved.

```
public String toHtml(int dec)
{
    String[] colors = {"#C0C0C0","#FFFFFF"};
    String f = "%-"+(getLongestValue()+dec+1)+"."+dec+"f";
    String res = "";
    for(int r = 0;r<rows;r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0;c<columns;c++)
        {
            res += "<span style=\"background-color:"+colors[(r+c)%2]+";\">"+String.format(f, contents[r][c])+"</span>";
        }
        res += "<p>";
    }
    return res;
}
```

which creates the HTML text to be displayed. The method getLongestValue() returns the largest length of any number before its decimal place in the array 'contents'.

and

```
newOutput("New Matrix ["+name+"]<br>"+m.toHtml());

public void newOutput(String s)
{
    JLabel l = new JLabel("<html>"+s+"<br></html>");
    l.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",1,18));
    jPanel1.add(l);
}
```

which adds the label to the output window

Also, here is the toString() method for reference

```
public String toString()
{
    String f = "%-"+(getLongestValue()+3)+".2f ";
    String res = "";
    for(int r = 0;r<rows;r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0;c<columns;c++)
        {
            res += String.format(f, contents[r][c]);
        }
        res += "\n";
    }
    return res;
}
```

output of the Matrix through toString()
 [toString Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFTIM.png)

A more extreme version
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQKnB.png]

In this case the program should have found that the largest values were -15 or -20 and set the size of the format length to 6( 3 for the length, 2 for the decimal places and 1 for the decimal) but instead it doesnt appear that any of the values, besides the two I mentioned, are following the format.

Here is the output of toString() for the previous example
 [toString() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wet2.png)

Comment: Can you precisely write what you would have expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes it, the spaces arent being represented correctly as monospaced

```
public String toHtml(int dec)
{
    String[] colors = {"#C0C0C0","#FFFFFF"};
    String f = "%-"+(getLongestValue()+dec+2)+"."+dec+"f";
    String res = "";
    for(int r = 0;r<rows;r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0;c<columns;c++)
        {
            res += "<span style=\"background-color:"+colors[(r+c)%2]+";\">"+
                    String.format(f, contents[r][c]).replaceAll("\\s", ((char)160)+"")+"</span>";
        }
        res += "<p>";
    }
    return res+"";
}
```